# Updating react component text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new with react and I'm trying to update some react components after submiting a form. Indeed the form can get some object and once the object is retrieved we can display some texte such as "Error while trying to get the object" or "Loading..." or "Object retrieved with success"
This is my state :

```
interface IState {
  inputText: string;
  isFetching: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
  cvs: CvModel[];
}
```

I got this code in order to render my form and text :

```
export default () => (
  <div>
      <FormFindCvContainer />
      <hr/>
      <DetailCvSearchContainer />
  </div>
);
```

Once the submit event is triggered, I got this reducer :

```
export default function cvs(state: IState = initialState, action: any) {
  let newState: IState;
  switch (action.type) {
      case REQUEST_FIND_CV_BY_NAME:
          newState = {...state};
          newState.inputText = action.name;
          newState.isFetching = true;
          newState.isError = false;
          return newState;
      case RECEIVE_CV_BY_NAME:
          newState = {...state};
          newState.isFetching = false;
          newState.isError = false;
          newState.cvs = [...state.cvs, action.cv];
          return newState;
      case ERROR_RECEIVE_CV_BY_NAME:
          newState = {...state};
          newState.isFetching = false;
          newState.isError = true;
          return newState;
      default:
          return state;
  }
}
```

And I finally got this code for displaying the text :

```
class DetailCvSearchContainer extends React.Component<IProps, undefined> {
  render() {
      let result = <div></div>;
      if (this.props.isFetching) {
          result = <h2>Loading...</h2>;
      } else if (this.props.isError) {
          result = <div>No CV</div>;
      }
      return result;
  }
}
```

If I try to find some cv and it doesn't exist it displays "No CV".
The problem is that if I come back to the home page and go to the form to find cv, the text "No CV" is still displayed. But I didn't make my search yet.
How can I make it to dislpay nothing when I come the first time to the form page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DetailCvSearchContainer extends React.Component<IProps, undefined> {
  render() {
    let result = <div></div>;
    if (this.props.isFetching) {
      result = <h2>Loading...</h2>;
    } else if (this.props.isError) {
      result = <div>No CV</div>;
    } else if(//check if cv is empty object or something){
      result = <div>Search for CV</div>
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

This should work. I dont know what your initial state is but you can set the cv field to null so you can check if you have performed a fetch or not.

Comment: If I let that it will keep ating like I see. The first time, when the cv searched didn"t exist, I dispatched an action that updated my state : isError is now true.
I come back to the home page an I go to the form page. Before doing anything, the text "no cv" is displayed because indeed when it checks "isError" it comes to be true

Comment: O I see. You can easily achieve the behavior you want using local state. You must not push everything to redux store. If you still want to use the redux store you can dispatch an action to reset the form values to the default ones whenever you load the form